# I need to validate Tabcontroll in winform c#, I want show a message before selecting another tab

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, tabs

I want to show a message before selecting another tab if Message result is 'NO' then it should remain in the current tab if message result is YES then selected tab should open.
I have tried following code.
''

```
'private void tbRWINV_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e){
    if (dgvSaleReturnWintoutInvoice.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DialogResult msg = new DialogResult();
                msg = MessageBox.Show("The data entered for return will be lost if you move to other Tab", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (msg == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    tbRWINV.TabIndex = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

'''

Comment: `TabControl.Selecting += ...; ` ?

Comment: Please explain a little bit....?

Comment: Loathing means that you should use `TabControl`'s `Selecting` event.

Comment: Ok but how can i validate it

Answer (score 5):

The `TabControlCancelEventArgs` event object has a `bool Cancel` property that will cancel the tab change. E.g:

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    TabControl tc = new TabControl();
    public MyForm() {
        //...
        tc.Selecting += tc_Selecting;
    }

    void tc_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to change tabs?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        e.Cancel = (r == DialogResult.No);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Its working perfectly what i want